# Determine Azure Web Role's instance IP address

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-cloud-services

The IP address I am looking for is not the VIP, nor the private IP address that is given to the role instance, but the *public IP address* that you can assign to each instance using this configuration:

```
  <NetworkConfiguration>
    <AddressAssignments>
      <InstanceAddress roleName="WebRole1">
        <PublicIPs>
          <PublicIP name="public" />
        </PublicIPs>
      </InstanceAddress>
    </AddressAssignments>
  </NetworkConfiguration>
```

Using Powershell Cmdlets, one is then able to find the IP address given to each instance like this:

```
PS C:\> Get-AzureService -ServiceName "rr-testservice" | Get-AzureRole -InstanceDetails
```

Which will output the results, like this:

```
InstanceErrorCode            :
InstanceFaultDomain          : 0
InstanceName                 : WebRole1_IN_0
InstanceSize                 : Small
InstanceStateDetails         :
InstanceStatus               : ReadyRole
InstanceUpgradeDomain        : 0
RoleName                     : WebRole1
DeploymentID                 : 69a82ec9bb094c31a1b79021c0f3bbf2
IPAddress                    : 100.79.164.151
PublicIPAddress              : 137.135.135.186
PublicIPName                 : public
PublicIPIdleTimeoutInMinutes :
PublicIPDomainNameLabel      :
PublicIPFqdns                : {}
ServiceName                  : rr-testservice
OperationDescription         : Get-AzureRole
OperationId                  : 00400634-f65d-095b-947f-411e69b9a053
OperationStatus              : Succeeded
```

Where in this case the IP addresses **137.135.135.186** and **137.135.133.191** are the ones I am looking for to retrieve **in .net / c#** (in the role instance itself)

Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make use of [`Azure Management Libraries`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Management.Libraries) which are essentially a wrapper over `Azure Service Management API` like PowerShell Cmdlets.

I wrote a simple console application where I made use of these libraries to fetch the IP address of all instances of my cloud service:

```
    static void GetCloudServiceDetails()
    {
        var subscriptionId = "<your azure subscription id>";
        var managementCertDataFromPublishSettingsFile = "<management cert data from a publish settings file>";
        var cert = new X509Certificate2(Convert.FromBase64String(managementCertDataFromPublishSettingsFile));
        var credentials = new CertificateCloudCredentials(subscriptionId, cert);
        var computeManagementClient = new ComputeManagementClient(credentials);
        var cloudServiceName = "<your cloud service name>";
        var cloudServiceDetails = computeManagementClient.HostedServices.GetDetailed(cloudServiceName);
        var deployments = cloudServiceDetails.Deployments;
        foreach (var deployment in deployments)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Deployment Slot: " + deployment.DeploymentSlot);
            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------------------");
            foreach(var instance in deployment.RoleInstances)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Instance name: " + instance.InstanceName + "; IP Address: " + string.Join(", ", instance.PublicIPs.Select(c => c.Address.ToString())));
            }
        }
    }
```

You could very well use this code for your Cloud Service.

Comment: It works, kind of. However, I feel it's kind of hacky that you need to use the Management APIs to get the public IP endpoint when you should be able to get it through ```RoleEnvironment``` or something like that.

Comment: I don't think RoleEnvironment would work because if I'm not mistaken, public IP is assigned to the load balancer sitting in front of your role's instances.

Comment: That *kind of* makes sense indeed.