# Azure: How to get the site URL value for a Cloud Service

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, azure-cloud-services

I'm deploying a range of cloud services on Azure, each one spawning a listener on an address that looks like: `http://+80/<the rest of the url>`

I would like them to register their endpoints on start. The problem is that I could not find a way to get the URL using the `RoleEnvironment` and `InstanceEndpoints` structures. The only valid info I could retrieve was the private IP which in my case is not useful for the clients of the endpoint.

Do you know if there is any way of obtaining the so called `Site URL` (Azure dashboard) that looks like: `http://<service_name>.cloudapp.net` ?

Comment: Have you tried using Service management API- GetDeployment method? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460804.aspx

Comment: The web API for Azure requires setting up a certificate, which doesn't seem trivial. Plus, in order to get the settings, you need to pass the name of the hosted service.

Comment: Meanwhile, this thread seems to have the right answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32036049/determine-azure-web-roles-instance-ip-address

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `Site URL` of a Cloud Service by using the [Get-AzureDeployment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495146.aspx) cmdlet in Powershell

```
Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName $serviceName -Slot staging
```

This returns a host of information including the `Site Url`. Use `-Slot production` for production services.